# Why does using <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MySetting")%> cause href attribute not to render in asp:HyperLink?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, webforms, server-tags

I am trying to bind a HyperLink control's NavigateUrl property in the markup using a server tag like so:

`<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkHelp" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HelpUrl")%>'>Text</asp:HyperLink>`

The IDE recognizes it and I even get intellisense, but the tag ends up rendering without the `href` attribute.  I've discovered `<%$ AppSettings:HelpUrl%>` and I have started using this, but I don't get intellisense with it.  That's not a deal breaker, but intellisense is just nice.  That's a question for another time, though, so I am mainly just wanting to know why using `<%# %>` causes the `href` attribute not to render.

Comment: Do you call `Bind` method on this HyperLink control on it's container?

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
NavigateUrl='<%$ ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HelpUrl"] %>'
```

Comment: Just found this in the same google search for this answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx